# Elasticsearch and C# - query to find exact matches over strings

Tags: c#, .net, database, elasticsearch, nest

I need a way to search documents using a plain exact match over two or multiple fields which are of type "string" and "integer".

I'd like to avoid standard query as I don't care about scoring or best match, just a yes/no outcome if both the fields match or not.

I know I can do it using filters but I got only example queries using JSON format. I'd like to do such search in a C# environment.

this is my mapping:

```
{
   "reviewer-test-index": {
      "aliases": {},
      "mappings": {
         "historyRecord": {
            "properties": {
               "groupName": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "groupNo": {
                  "type": "integer"
               },
               "instrType": {
                  "type": "integer"
               },
               "instrumentAddress": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "insturmentName": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "macAddr": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "uhhVersion": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         },         
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "creation_date": "1434557536720",
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "number_of_replicas": "0",
            "version": {
               "created": "1050299"
            },
            "uuid": "FfQADLGVQVOPV3913exKsw"
         }
      },
      "warmers": {}
   }
}
```

I also tried to make a JSON query but I get 0 hits:

```
GET _search
{
  "query" :{
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "match_all": { }
    },
   "filter": {
      "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {"term" : { "macAddr" : "000A8D810F5A" } },
                {"term" : { "insturmentName" : "Amin's furnace" } },
                {"term" : { "instrumentAddress" : "8D810F5A"}},
                {"term" : { "uhhVersion" :  "v2.5"}},
                {"term" : { "groupName" :  "Amin's Group"}},
                {"term" : { "groupNo" :  2}},
                {"term" : { "instrType" :  60}}
            ]
         }
    }
  }
  }
}

Response:

{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 4,
      "successful": 3,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filtered query with term filter:

```
{
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "match_all": { }
    },
    "filter": {
      "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {"term" : { "macaddress" : "your_mac" } },
                {"term" : { "another_field" : 123 } }
            ]
         }
    }
  }
}
```

NEST version (replace `dynamic` with your response model):

```
var res = esclient.Search<dynamic>(q => q
            .Query(fq => fq
                .Filtered(fqq => fqq
                    .Query(qq => qq.MatchAll())
                    .Filter(ff => ff
                        .Bool(b => b
                            .Must(m1 => m1.Term("macaddress", "your_mac"))
                            .Must(m2 => m2.Term("another_field", 123))
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Updates base on provided mappings & response:

Here's something you need to notice first:

- We use `term` when we need to index & search keyword or id. In your case it's "macAddr" but the problem is you index it using standard analyzer (so `000A8D810F5A` will be transformed to `000a8d810f5a`), and search it using `term` (which will keep passed data as it ==> `000A8D810F5A`), then it will never match the indexed data: `000a8d810f5a`. 
  You can solve it by lower case the term before searching, or using `match` query. It maybe the same for case "instrumentAddress" & "uhhVersion" (I'm not sure because I dont have sample data).
- For case "insturmentName", "groupName" you're indexing **phrase** using standard analyzer. So data like "Amin's furnace" will be indexed as two terms `amin's`, `furnace`, and none of them match passed term `Amin's furnace`.
  In this case we can use `match` query to search (or `query_string` if you need more options)

So a quick fix will look like this:

```
GET _search
{
"query" :{
  "filtered": {
     "query": {
        "match_all": { }
      },
     "filter": {
       "bool" : {
        "must" : [
            {"match" : { "macAddr" : "000A8D810F5A" } },
            {"match" : { "insturmentName" : "Amin's furnace" } },
            {"match" : { "instrumentAddress" : "8D810F5A"}},
            {"term" : { "uhhVersion" :  "v2.5"}},
            {"match" : { "groupName" :  "Amin's Group"}},
            {"term" : { "groupNo" :  2}},
            {"term" : { "instrType" :  60}}
          ]
        }
       }
      }
     }
   }
```

If you can lower case search term for "macAddr", "instrumentAddress" then you can replace its match query to term query for better performance.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll accept the answer if you provide me the C# NEST code to do it

Comment: ok thank you! what if I want to do multiple matches over strings, let's say two filter rules ANDed together? this is my main problem :-)

Comment: You mean to match another field together with your macaddress ? You can update the question then I can update the answer to make it clear.

Comment: yes, exactly that... I've updated the question. thank you!

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'll give you +1 rep and accept the answer :-)

Comment: Check the answer, I updated it 30min ago. BTW using term filter or another kind of filter is depend on how you index data and the requirements.

Comment: mmm. for some strange reason the code returns me all the documents instead of just one

Comment: Can you post your mappings, some data & your query ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80804/discussion-between-duc-duong-and-g-g).

Comment: Unfortunately now I'm out of office. What about tomorrow? Thank u!

Comment: You can update your mappings, query to the question when you're free. Then we can continue